# How can i search for the same input parameter

Tags: sql-server

My input parameter is :

```
exec [dbo].[MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER]  N'2040,2041,2044,2047,2048'
```

I need to search in a data base where i have to search in those inputs like this

```
Product IN ('2040','2041','2044','2047','204048')
```

How can i convert the input parameter to put it inside the " Product" search one at a time

UPDATE

I need to split the input to be list of strings to be able to search in them

Comment: question should be more detailed this information is not enough

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a string like this

```
N'2040,2041,2044,2047,2048'
```

and you are expecting it to be parsed as comma seperated values..so you need to parse the input first..

you could use split [string available from here](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1) and do the parse like below in your proc..

```
select * from split_String(@String,',')
```

and pass the above input in the place where you are passing string in stored proc

split string source code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Numbers
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN
   (
       SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
         CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
       FROM dbo.Numbers
       WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
         AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
   );
GO
```

**Numbers table :**

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers
(
    Number INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
        WITH FILLFACTOR = 100
)

INSERT INTO Numbers
SELECT
    (a.Number * 256) + b.Number AS Number
FROM 
    (
        SELECT number
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE 
            type = 'P'
            AND number <= 255
    ) a (Number),
    (
        SELECT number
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE 
            type = 'P'
            AND number <= 255
    ) b (Number)
GO
```

Comment: I have an Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'. error

Comment: you will need to install string split function from the link  pasted

Comment: my sql database compatibility is 120 and it cannot be higher

Comment: sorry, i pasted the wrong link, you will need to install from here,no need to change compat level:https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you want to execute that store procedure with different parameters, which have to be included in the IN clause you wrote.

You can do this:

```
DECLARE @Product INT = 0

-- Iterate over all products
WHILE ( 1 = 1) 
BEGIN  

  -- Get next productID 
  --Since you didn't show us how is your product tables I had to make up a little,
  SELECT TOP 1 @Product = Product
  FROM Products
  WHERE Product > @Product 
  ORDER BY Product

  -- Exit loop if no more products
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK;

  -- call your sproc
  EXEC [dbo].[MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER] @Product

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic query and pass the IDs in the query directly but this option is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Therefore, you should split up the IDs first and then join it with your actual table. Your procedure should be like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER] @Ids NVARCHAR(1000)
AS

--DECLARE @Ids NVARCHAR(1000) = N'2040,2041,2044,2047,2048' 
;WITH CTE
AS(
SELECT  CAST('<N>' + REPLACE(@Ids,',','</N><N>') + '</N>' AS XML) [XMLids]
)
SELECT  T.a.value('.', 'INT') AS ID,yt.* 
FROM    CTE
        CROSS APPLY CTE.XMLids.nodes('/N') AS T(a)
        INNER JOIN dbo.YourTable yt
            ON T.a.value('.', 'INT') = yt.Product
```

NOTE: I assumed that the IDs are `INT` by default, if not, please update the code. You can replace the `JOIN` with `IN` clause easily if required.